# C# Entity Framnework Lambda select con IN

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, lambda

tengo la siguiente consulta sql, que debo pasar a lambda de entity framework:

```
select EVENTSOURCE, SPEED,LOCATION_X,LOCATION_Y,LOCATION_Z, IsNull(SATELLITES, 0) As SATELLITES 
from PRODUCTION_EVENT 
where EVENT_OID 
    IN (select max(EVENT_OID) EVENT_OID from PRODUCTION_EVENT GROUP BY EVENTSOURCE)
```

para esto, he logrado lo siguiente:

```
var event_oids = _context.ProductionEvents.Select(x => x.EVENT_OID).Max();
var algo = _context.ProductionEvents
                 .Select(x => new {
                        EVENT_OID = x.EVENT_OID,
                        EVENTSOURCE = x.EVENTSOURCE,
                        SPEED = x.SPEED,
                        LOCATION_X = x.LOCATION_X,
                        LOCATION_Y = x.LOCATION_Y,
                        LOCATION_Z = x.LOCATION_Z,
                        SATELLITES = x.SATELLITES })
                 .Where(x => event_oids.Contains(x.EVENT_OID))
                 .GroupBy(x => x.EVENTSOURCE)
                 .ToList();
```

Este código me esta marcando un error en la clausula Where, que indica:
***CS1929   'float' no contiene una definición para 'Contains' y la mejor sobrecarga del método de extensión 'MemoryExtensions.Contains(ReadOnlySpan, float)' requiere un receptor del tipo 'ReadOnlySpan' TeckWebApi***

el campo EVENT_OID es efectivamente del tipo float
Si quito el .Max(), deja de marcar el error.
Que tendría que hacer para poder incluir el operador Max()??

por otra parte, en el where al ejecutar el código (quitando el .Max()), en el GroupBy me marca este error en tiempo de ejecución:
***.GroupBy(x => x.EVENTSOURCE)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.***

Aquí no entiendo porque no lo puede traducir, ya que el campo por el cual esta haciendo el group, esta presente en la consulta.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos y gracias por leer

Comment: Los tipos de punto flotante no tienen el método Contains(), como usaste el metodo Max este te devuelve un solo valor (float), si necesitas hacer el Contains te recomiendo que hagas un .ToString() a tu campo event_oids...

Comment: Déjame entender lo que quieres: Debes traer los PRODUCTION_EVENT que sean iguales al máximo EVENT_OID????

Comment: Veo que en la primera consulta hecha en c# para sacar "event_oids" la haces solo con el valor maximo de ese campo, por ende solo retornara un solo valor, pero en la consulta en sql que pretendes hacer, le haces un group by EVENTSOURCE, lo cual en C# no le agregas. Entonces cuando quieres hacer el contains pues no puedes porque esta no es una lista de valores, si no un solo valor float que es el valor de la consulta de "event_oids" la cual solo retorna un solo valor.